# How to get the nearest selected dropdown value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the selected value of the select dropdown but I am getting undefined. I have a comment icon on the list and when I click on it then I am getting undefined.
I tried some alerts in the script but all are not working.

Any help with this?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#wip_remarkUpdate', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).closest('.actionslist li .wip_fileStatus').find('select').val());

  alert($('.wip_fileStatus').find("select").val());
  alert($('#workInProgress').closest('select').find(':selected').val());

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<div id="workInProgress">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
        <th>Test4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td>asdasdasd asd asd</td>
        <td>alskda asd</td>
        <td>dkasdkad</td>
        <td>
          <ul class="actionslist">
            <li>
              <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect wip_fileStatus" data-id="130">
                <option value="" disabled="" selected="">File Status</option>
                <option value="1">Approved</option>
                <option value="2" selected="">Aggrement</option>
                <option value="3">Rejected</option>
                <option value="4">Dropped</option>
              </select>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="wip_remarkUpdate" data-id="130"><i class="far fa-comment"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td>asdasdasd asd asd</td>
        <td>alskda asd</td>
        <td>dkasdkad</td>
        <td>
          <ul class="actionslist">
            <li>
              <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect wip_fileStatus" data-id="130">
                <option value="" disabled="" selected="">File Status</option>
                <option value="1">Approved</option>
                <option value="2">Aggrement</option>
                <option value="3">Rejected</option>
                <option value="4" selected="">Dropped</option>
              </select>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="wip_remarkUpdate" data-id="130"><i class="far fa-comment"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find as below.

Also use **class** instead of **id**, because ID is unique things in document so class you can use..

```js
$(document).on('click', '.wip_remarkUpdate', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  //alert($(this).closest('.actionslist li .wip_fileStatus').find('select').val());
  alert( $(this).parents('.actionslist').find('select').find(':selected').val() );
  
  alert( $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').find('select').val() );
 


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<div id="workInProgress">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
        <th>Test4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td>asdasdasd asd asd</td>
        <td>alskda asd</td>
        <td>dkasdkad</td>
        <td>
          <ul class="actionslist">
            <li>
              <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect wip_fileStatus" data-id="130">
                <option value="" disabled="" selected="">File Status</option>
                <option value="1">Approved</option>
                <option value="2" selected="">Aggrement</option>
                <option value="3">Rejected</option>
                <option value="4">Dropped</option>
              </select>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="wip_remarkUpdate" data-id="130"><i class="far fa-comment wip_remarkUpdate"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td>asdasdasd asd asd</td>
        <td>alskda asd</td>
        <td>dkasdkad</td>
        <td>
          <ul class="actionslist">
            <li>
              <select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect wip_fileStatus" data-id="130">
                <option value="" disabled="" selected="">File Status</option>
                <option value="1">Approved</option>
                <option value="2">Aggrement</option>
                <option value="3">Rejected</option>
                <option value="4" selected="">Dropped</option>
              </select>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="wip_remarkUpdate" data-id="130"><i class="far fa-comment wip_remarkUpdate"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with my code? you change it from closest to parents. right?

Comment: i have first find the parent and in that find the select and selected value, there is also other ways to achieve it.

Comment: It's working for me. Can you share the other way also?

Comment: @NarenVerma you can find just using `li` as updated line.

Comment: Can you help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465008/how-to-expand-the-nearest-div-when-click-on-the-plus-sign-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I have find you are not getting the perfect access of select.
Just replace this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#wip_remarkUpdate', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest('ul').find('li').find('select').val());
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide explanations with your answers.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can not give same id to all a tag give a classname instead

```
$(document).on('click', '.wip_remarkUpdate', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).parent("ul").children("li").first().find("select").val() );
});
```