# How to expand the nearest div when click on the plus sign using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a plus sign and when the user clicks on plus then it will display the div which displays none on page load. I mean I have to display the div where the class is viewMoreStatus.

I tried the below code but it's not working.

```js
$('.expandExtra').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".expandExtra").removeClass('change_sign');
  if ($this.find('.viewMoreStatus').hasClass('show')) {
    $this.removeClass('change_sign');
    $this.find('.viewMoreStatus').removeClass('show');
    $this.parents('.custom_fields').find('editLeadFileStatus').find('viewMoreStatus').slideDown();

  } else {
    $this.addClass('change_sign');
    $this.parents('.custom_fields').find('editLeadFileStatus').find('viewMoreStatus').slideDown();

  }
});
```

```css
.viewMoreStatus {
  display: none
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra::before {
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra.change_sign::before {
  content: "\f056";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="custom_fields medication_info" id="custom_fields">

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing1</h2>
    <h3>Testing1</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing2</h2>
    <h3>Testing2</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing3</h2>
    <h3>Testing3</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: use `$this.siblings('.viewMoreStatus').show();`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, Yes, it's displaying now. but how do I close previous one

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: better to use `slideUp` as answered by @Mamum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code. You are targeting the parent (`.custom_fields`) of all elements, you should target only the parent of clicked element (`.editLeadFileStatus`). You can check the visibility of the element with `:visible` selector.

Try the following way:

```js
$('.expandExtra').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  //if want it like accordion
  //$('.expandExtra').removeClass('change_sign');
  //else
  $this.removeClass('change_sign');
  if ($this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').is(':visible')) {
    $this.removeClass('change_sign');
    $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').slideUp();
  } else {
    $this.addClass('change_sign');
  // slideup all other if want it like accordion
  //$('.viewMoreStatus').not($this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus')).slideUp();
    $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').slideDown();
  }
});
```

```css
.viewMoreStatus {
  display: none
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra::before {
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra.change_sign::before {
  content: "\f056";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="custom_fields medication_info" id="custom_fields">

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing1</h2>
    <h3>Testing1</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing2</h2>
    <h3>Testing2</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing3</h2>
    <h3>Testing3</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The description is to help me to understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey, No, I don't want accordion.  I need when the user clicks on plus then it will display the div.

Comment: @Mamun, but you can update both answers for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something below with use of `show()` and `hide()`

```js
$('.expandExtra').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.viewMoreStatus').hide();
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".expandExtra").removeClass('change_sign');
  if ($this.find('.viewMoreStatus').hasClass('show')) {
    $this.removeClass('change_sign');
    $this.find('.viewMoreStatus').removeClass('show');
    $this.parents('.custom_fields').find('editLeadFileStatus').find('viewMoreStatus').slideDown();
    
    $this.siblings('.viewMoreStatus').hide();

  } else {
   
    $this.addClass('change_sign');
    $this.parents('.custom_fields').find('editLeadFileStatus').find('viewMoreStatus').slideDown();
     $this.siblings('.viewMoreStatus').show();

  }
});
```

```css
.viewMoreStatus {
  display: none
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra::before {
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra.change_sign::before {
  content: "\f056";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="custom_fields medication_info" id="custom_fields">

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing1</h2>
    <h3>Testing1</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing2</h2>
    <h3>Testing2</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing3</h2>
    <h3>Testing3</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I removed     $this.parents('.custom_fields').find('editLeadFileStatus').find('viewMoreStatus').slideDown();

Comment: if show() and hide() ok for you then u can remove it, also you can follow answer of Mamum and use one which is better for your need.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.expandExtra').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".expandExtra").removeClass('change_sign');
  if ($this.find('.viewMoreStatus').hasClass('show')) {
    $this.toggleClass('change_sign');
    $this.find('.viewMoreStatus').slideUp(); 

  } else {
    $this.toggleClass('change_sign');
    $('.viewMoreStatus').slideUp()
    $this.siblings('.viewMoreStatus').slideDown()
  }
});
```

```css
.viewMoreStatus {
  display: none
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra::before {
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra.change_sign::before {
  content: "\f056";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="custom_fields medication_info" id="custom_fields">

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing1</h2>
    <h3>Testing1</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing2</h2>
    <h3>Testing2</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing3</h2>
    <h3>Testing3</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$this.parents('.custom_fields').find('editLeadFileStatus').find('viewMoreStatus').slideDown();` and `$this.parents('.custom_fields').find('editLeadFileStatus').find('viewMoreStatus').slideDown();` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: until you have element `<viewMoreStatus></viewMoreStatus>`

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can update your code with slidedown and slide up

```
$('.expandExtra').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
$(".expandExtra").removeClass('change_sign');
if ($this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').hasClass('show')) {
  $this.removeClass('change_sign');
   $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').slideUp();
  $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').removeClass("show");
} else {
  $this.addClass('change_sign');
  $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').slideDown();
  $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').addClass("show");
}
});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

- Simplify the classes (not everything needs a class and id is practically useless),
- Use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to switch between `.expand` and `.collapse` classes for `.icon` (use one unchanging class: `.icon`, and two alternating classes: `.expand`, and `.collapse`)
- Use [`.slideToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) for the `.status` expansion and collapse.
- `$('.icon')` is `$(this)`. Reference `$(this)` as the starting point when traversing from `$(this)` up to the `header.title` (via [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)) then to the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) `section.status`

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Click any .icon
$('.icon').on('click', function(e) {
  // Toggle that specific .icon classes .expand and .collapse
  $(this).toggleClass('expand collapse');
  /*
  Then go up to that specific .icon parent .title then go to that
  .title next .status and toggle it up or down
  */
  $(this).closest('.title').next('.status').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 3vw/1.2 Arial
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.65rem
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.35rem
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.2rem
}

hr {
  margin-top: 8vh
}

header,
article {
  margin-left: 3vw
}

header h2 {
  margin-left: -2.25vw
}

header>p {
  margin: -4vh 0;
}

/*
Apply the CSS properties/values that do not change to the base class
*/
.icon {
  text-indent: -3.75vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}

/*
Apply the CSS properties with alternating values to the switching classes
*/
.expand::before {
  content: "\f055";
}

.collapse::before {
  content: "\f056";
}

.status {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 3vw
}

.status h4 {
  margin-bottom: -1vh
}

.status p {
  margin-bottom: 1vh
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="medication-info">
  <header>
    <h1>Medication Information</h1>
  </header>
  <hr>
  <article>
    <header class='title'>
      <h2><i class='icon expand'></i> Oxycodone</h2>
      <p><b>Brand name:</b> Oxycontin</p>
      <h3>Narcotic</h3>
      <p>It can treat moderate to severe pain.</p>
    </header>
    <section class="status">
      <h4>Controlled Substance</h4>
      <p>High risk for addiction and dependence. Can cause respiratory distress and death when taken in high doses or when combined with other substances, especially alcohol.</p>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS781US781&q=oxycontin&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjX1L6I3s3mAhVErZ4KHchhBtgQBSgAegQIDxAm&biw=1366&bih=663#">More info</a>
    </section>
  </article>
  <hr>
  <article>
    <header class='title'>
      <h2><i class='icon expand'></i> Methylphenidate</h2>
      <p><b>Brand name:</b> Ritalin</p>
      <h3>Stimulant</h3>
      <p>It can treat ADHD and narcolepsy.</p>
    </header>
    <section class="status">
      <h4>Controlled Substance</h4>
      <p>Can cause rapid or irregular heartbeat, delirium, panic, psychosis, and heart failure.</p>
      <a href='http://www.drugfree.org/drug-guide/prescription-stimulants?utm_source=google&utm_medium=kp&utm_campaign=stimulants'>More info</a>
    </section>
  </article>
  <hr>
</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check child of parent here

```js
$('.expandExtra').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $(".expandExtra").removeClass('change_sign');
  if ($this.parent().find('div.viewMoreStatus').hasClass('show')) {
    $this.removeClass('change_sign');
    $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').hide();
$this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').removeClass("show");
  } else {
    $this.addClass('change_sign');
    $this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').show();
$this.parent().find('.viewMoreStatus').addClass("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.viewMoreStatus {
  display: none
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra::before {
  content: "\f055";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
}

.editLeadFileStatus span.expandExtra.change_sign::before {
  content: "\f056";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="custom_fields medication_info" id="custom_fields">

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing1</h2>
    <h3>Testing1</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing2</h2>
    <h3>Testing2</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row editLeadFileStatus">
    <span class="expandExtra"></span>
    <h2>Testing3</h2>
    <h3>Testing3</h3>
    <div class="viewMoreStatus">hide on page load and display on click</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```